# javac can't find classes in .jar even though they are present?

Tags: java, ant, compilation, compiler-errors, javac

I'm including a rather large JAR file during compilation that I'm generating using Altova MapForce.  The JAR file was around 65MB and compilation was working fine.  I needed to add a bunch more mappings, so I did, regenerated my JAR, and tried building again.  The JAR is now around 80MB.

Now I get all kinds of "cannot find symbol" error messages even though I've opened the JAR to verify that the symbols are there!  Am I hitting some upper limit on JAR sizes?  There are over 75,000 classes inside the JAR file.

What's weird is that Eclipse auto-completion works just fine with the new JAR; I only get these errors when building.

I'm using Ant if that makes any difference.

Thanks,

Brian

**EDIT**: Something else strange:  I turned on the verbose output from javac.  It seems that I start getting compile errors even before all of the classes are loaded:

```
[javac] [loading com\mycompany\myproject\*************************.class)]
[javac] [loading com\mycompany\myproject\*************************.class)]
[javac] [loading com\mycompany\myproject\*************************.class)]
[javac] [loading com\mycompany\myproject\*************************.class)]
[javac] [loading com\mycompany\myproject\*************************.class)]
[javac] C:\Users\*************************.java:38: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : class *************************
[javac] location: package com.mycompany.myproject.*************************
[javac] import com.mycompany.myproject.*************************;
[javac]                                                      ^
[javac] [loading com\altova\TraceProvider.class(com\altova:TraceProvider.class)]
[javac] [loading com\altova\io\StringInput.class(com\altova\io:StringInput.class)]
[javac] [loading com\altova\io\StringOutput.class(com\altova\io:StringOutput.class)]
```

Comment: you can also turn on verbose output with ant to verify your classpath is correct....

Comment: Did you blot out some of your output or is there really a class being generated with the name *************************?

Comment: It's blotted out to protect the innocent.

Comment: I wouldn't trust the ordering of the javac statements at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've solved the problem.  All I did was regenerate my JAR (I didn't change anything!) and it worked.  Seems like it was just a fluke.

Sorry to waste everyone's time!

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see the specific compiler errors you're getting, your classpath, etc. If it works from eclipse and not in ant, it's likely to be a classpath issue, i.e. your ant script is not setting the same classpath as your project settings in eclipse has.

I work on one project that has a jar file larger than 80MB no problem, and I don't think there's an upper limit on number of classes in a jar file or anything like that. the size of the jar and the number of classes it contains is unlikely to be your problem.

you can try writing a simple test main program that just imports the classes in question, and compile that with javac with only that jar on your classpath. if that test doesn't work, you know you've got a problem with the jar you're using. if it doesn't work, is has got to be either an ant issue or similar.

can you post your ant build target, and the verbose output of ant?

Comment: I just edited my question with some more info.  Any thoughts?  The JAR I'm trying to load from is present on the classpath according to the javac verbose output.

Comment: I edited my answer a bit, I think you should try compiling from the command line with just that jar and a main class that does a few imports. next step, get that class working with your ant build script.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this problem, when building via Ant on Jenkins.
The class which is not found is shown loading after the error: "Cannot find symbol" shows up in the verbose output.  Tried rebuilding numerous times, no joy.

Finally, I went to the class importing the class not found, and changed the order of imports so the problem class was nearer the top.  This is a temporary fix, as soon as someone organizes the imports in Eclipse, they will be sorted in an order that Javac will fail to load.  We may have to rename the class, so it sorts to the top of the imports.

After some more research, I found this is related to bug 7101822 in Java, where eager loading of the classes can result in "Cannot find symbol" error.

http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7101822

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: Agreed, revised to an answer.

Comment: Good job fixing it. Somebody had flagged it for deletion as not an answer, but it appears you edited it in time to save it from my axe. I'm marking it as "Looks OK".